# Why are the geranium leaves folding downwards?

Tags: leaves, geraniums

Does anyone know why the leaves are folding downwards? The leaves feel flimsy and thin.

I'm new to gardening, and this is my first time taking care of a young geranium plant. Please help me and give me tips! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Is the plant inside or outside? If outside, what have the overnight temperatures been?

Comment: The plant is inside